# Mac OS app based on Applescript

Tags: objective-c, xcode, excel, download, applescript

I'm new to Xcode as well as I am to AppleScript

All I need is to run an AppleScript in an Xcode application.

Bassically, the application is downloading pictures from a url list in Excel and renames the files acording the list in Excel

Here is the applescript code :

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
  set filenames to value of every cell of range "K3:K200" of sheet "Image_Moves" of document 1
  set URLs to value of every cell of range "L3:L200" of sheet "Image_Moves" of document 1
end tell

repeat with i from 1 to count URLs
  if (item i of filenames is not missing value) and (item i of URLs is not missing value) then
    set thisFname to quoted form of (POSIX path of ({path to desktop, "Image_Moves:"} as text) & item i of filenames)
    set thisUrl to quoted form of item i of URLs
    set status to (do shell script "curl -s -o " & thisFname & space & thisUrl)
  end if
end repeat

try
  tell application "Finder"
    delete (every item of folder ("Image_Moves") whose name begins with "0")
  end tell
on error
  display dialog ("Error. Couldn't Move the File") buttons {"OK"}
end try
```

Comment: Unclear what your problem is. How is it related to Xcode at all? What is an Xcode application?

Comment: Eiko, I have a version of Applescript and I want to turn it into an Mac OS, app. How is it related to Xcode ? well, from what I know, you can do this with X-Code, right ?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, you can write a full application in AppleScript with the "Cocoa-AppleScript" template. Also, you can compile and execute an AppleScript with the NSAppleScript class. If your question is just about making an AppleScript executable, use Save As... in Script Editor and save your AppleScript as an application.

HTH

Comment: Thank you SteffX, I'd be very happy if you can help me to compile my Applescript with the NSAppleScript class. please pleas please